# Can I put batch api callbacks in an include file?

Tags: batch-operations

I have a .module file that is getting quite lengthy, and I added some batch functionality to it. I put the form and batch callbacks in a separate .inc file, and added the appropriate `file` directive to the menu array.

I was able to get the form submission to work, but the batch api threw the error `Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function '_my_batch_callback' not found or invalid function name in _batch_process()`. I got this error until I moved the batch callbacks into the .module file.

Is it possible to put the batch callbacks into a separate include file? Or have I just done something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there is a [file directive](https://www.drupal.org/node/180528) in the batch array. I found it was necessary to include `drupal_get_path` to fully reference the file's path.

```
'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MY_MODULE') . '/includes/my-batch.inc'
```